# ARKit and Vuforia in the same project (different scenes)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, arkit

How can I add Vuforia and ARKit in the same Unity project 9use them in different scenes?

So I have a scene where I use Vuforia and a scene where I use ARKit.
I want to switch between the scenes.

The problem is that If I have Vuforia and ARKit in the same project, nothing works. ARKit scene (which use only ARKit) doesn't work properly, the same with Vuforia screen.

Comment: You should be able to use ARKit and Vuforia in the same project. I am and they work fine together. Just make sure you're using two different view controllers instead of a single VC and swapping views in/out or something weird like that.

Comment: @JohnScalo looks like it works only with legacy Vuforia version...

Comment: I'm on SDK v6.5.23. Is that legacy?